# the difference between RIP and OSPF

Tags: ospf, rip

I was working with CISCO and to create a path between switches my teachers told me that I can use 2 types of protocols, 
but they did not explain to me what *differences* there are between the two:

> 1. RIP =>   Routing Information Protocol
> 2. OSPF  =>  Open Shortest Path First

What's the difference?
What should I use if I only have 6 routers?

Comment: **I did not ask a question to judge the answer**!    
Please answer my question with all the words you want to utilize

Comment: Sadly, schoolwork is off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

In a non-trivial network, there are possibly multiple gateways leading from one subnet to a neighbor subnet. The gateways, or routers, need to be aware of which destination subnet can be reached through which one of their neighbors.

The routers can either be configured with (static) routes pointing to the next hop for a given destination subnet or they can learn these routes by interchanging information by a routing protocol.

There are various routing protocols around but most of them stick to two basic approaches:

1. distance-vector protocols (e.g. RIP): each router compiles a list of its own routes and passes it to its neighbors - distance-vector is rather simple to implement but usually has a rather slow convergence behavior in case of a change
2. link-state protocols (e.g. OSPF): each router compiles a list of its local links and their states and passes it to its neighbors - link-state requires more processing logic but has much better converge times than distance-vector

Answer (score 0):

First off, OSPF and RIP are routing protocols and operate in Network layer and Transport layer respectively in OSI model. They cannot be used with switches, as switches operate in data link layer. You probably elicited something confusing from your teacher, or your teacher himself is confused.

Comment: OMG, sorry you got the reason, **I've 6 routers, not switch!**

Comment: This is incorrect.  OSPF has a single metric.  On a Cisco router, it is based only on bandwidth.  Congestion, etc is not part of the metric calculation.  In fact it's not part of any protocols calculation.  Also, OSPF and RIP would be considered application layer, although neither fits the model exactly.